# how to pass two variable as single string to javascript function in Repeater : using DataBinder.Eval

Tags: c#, javascript, repeater

I want to pass two item as single string in javascript function:
Javascript function called on click of image, that is in repeater.

```
 <asp:Image  runat="server"  
onclick='<%# "playVideoFromHistroy("+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ChannelId") + "&&" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"WatchID") + ")" %>' />
```

But I got this Error :

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
>
> playVideoFromHistroy(1506&&3dmtR9ao2r4)

Comment: Wrap the parameter in quotes so your output looks like: `playVideoFromHistory('1506&&3dmtR9ao2r4')`

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by using string.Format : Posted here , so might be helpful to other :

```
onclick='<%# "playVideoFromHistroy("+ string.Format("\"{0}&&{1}\"", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ChannelId") , DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"WatchID")) + ")" %>'
```

My mistake : I did not passed those in qoutes.